# Game returning a number when counter specified as a char

Tags: java, eclipse

I decided to change my counter type from a number (1 or 2) to a letter (r or y). I have made the relevant changes to my code, however now when I place the counter, I dont get an r or a y, i get a number.

r displays as 114 and y displays as 121? Where has this number come from, as I have not specified it anywhere within my code?

Appreciate any help, cheers

Comment: `114` and `121` are the ascii values of `r` and `y` respectively and if you want a number to be printed as a character, either the variable type referencing the number needs to be `char` or while printing you may cast the number to `char` like `(char)114`

Comment: but i dont want a number to be printed, I want either r or y to be printed

Comment: Then either change the variable type from `int` or `long` to `char` or while printing just cast it to `char` like I described above. Basically when you write something like `int a = 'r'` and print the value of `a`, it will not print ascii value of `r` and not print `r` so if you want to print value of `a` as char, print `(char)a` rather than just `a`

Comment: I suggest making your comments an answer instead. @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi

Comment: @SacrificerXY: Added as answer as you suggested. Hope my explanation helps others.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a numeric variable type like `int` or `long` and assign a character like this,

```
long n = 'r';
System.out.println(n); // prints ascii value of r i.e 114
```

and you print the value of `n`, it will print the ascii value of `r` rather than character `r`

So if you want it to actually print `r`, either change the variable type to `char` like this,

```
char n = 'r';
System.out.println(n); // prints r now
```

Or, while printing the value of variable `n` cast it to `char` and then print,

```
int n = 'r';
System.out.println((char)n); // now it prints r
```

Hope my explanation helps and let me know if you further have any queries.